# SQL/ Linq query select from many to many

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have following (simplified) structure in my SQL database. 
[image]

Now I would like to select all groups where the user is not yet part of.
It would help if the query is written using Linq/Entity Framework but I can work with the SQL statement too.

I tried using Include (using EF):

```
.Include(g => g.Group_User)
```

in the query and than using a:

```
.Where(g => g.Group_User.UserId != userId)
```

but that did not work and is probably totally not the correct way of doing these kind of query's.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to select all groups where the user is not yet part of.

So you want all groups without a group-user with this `UserId`, so use `!Any` and `==`:

```
var q = db.Group.Include(g => g.Group_User)
    .Where(g => !g.Group_User.Any(gu => gu.UserId == userId));
```

Comment: Yes this worked, ReSharper is sugesting this change: `g.Group_AspNetUsers.All(gu => gu.AspNetUsersid != userId` is there a big difference between the two?

Comment: @lordvlad30: no, resharper always tries to avoid the `!`. Use what you find more readable. Both yield the same result and are equally efficient. I'd prefer the `!Any` because it's the translation of your requirement

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer and the help! (not enough reputation to upvote but you deserve it)